# How to sort res.data by _id?

Tags: javascript

My `res.data` always randomly sorted, how to sort `res.data` by `_id` ?

```
const [income, setIncome] = useState([]);
  const [perc, setPerc] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getIncome = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await userRequest.get("orders/income");
        setIncome(res.data);
        setPerc((res.data[1].total * 100) / res.data[0].total - 100);
        console.log(res.data);
      } catch {}
    };
    getIncome();
  }, []);
```

console.dev:

```
0: {_id: 10, total: 990}
1: {_id: 11, total: 20}
2: {_id: 6, total: 448}
3: {_id: 9, total: 700}
4: {_id: 8, total: 100}
5: {_id: 7, total: 900}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this to sort based on it:

```
res.data.sort((x, y) => x._id - y._id)
```

This will sort in ascending order based on the `_id` attribute for each item of the res.data array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for that:

```js
const data = [
  {_id: 10, total: 990},
  {_id: 11, total: 20},
  {_id: 6, total: 448},
  {_id: 9, total: 700},
  {_id: 8, total: 100},
  {_id: 7, total: 900}
]
const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => a._id - b._id)

console.log(data)
```

In this example I use subtraction "hack" do determinate order. It works only for numbers, if you want to compare strings, for example, you can pass custom compare function (`compareFunction(a, b)`) that returns:

- `> 0` - sort a after b
- `< 0` - sort a before b
- `=== 0` - keep original order of a and b

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `sort` function like this:

```
myArray = [{_id: 10, total: 990},
{_id: 11, total: 20},
{_id: 6, total: 448},
{_id: 9, total: 700},
{_id: 8, total: 100},
{_id: 7, total: 900}];

// now myArray is sorted "in place" in a descending order.
myArray.sort((a, b) => a._id - b._id);

// you can flip it so it is ordered in an ascending order:
myArray.sort((a, b) => b._id - a._id);
```

Notice that sorting by id is not recommended because there is no business logic related to the order of ids. Why should item 1 be shown before item 2?

The order should depend on a business-related field, for example, modified date.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you should sort the data directly from the API.

Otherwise, you can use the [Array#sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) once you get the data

```js
const arr = [{
  _id: 10,
  total: 990
}, {
  _id: 11,
  total: 20
}, {
  _id: 6,
  total: 448
}, {
  _id: 9,
  total: 700
}, {
  _id: 8,
  total: 100
}, {
  _id: 7,
  total: 900
}]

arr.sort((a, b) => a._id - b._id)
console.log(arr)
```